# GetMapping in Spring boot to exclude specific path variable match

Tags: java, spring-boot, get-mapping

I have a controller with the following GetMapping

```or-tag-here
@GetMapping(value = "/dawson/v1/{dataType}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> respondWithData(@PathVariable String dataType, @RequestParam(name = "minDate") String min_date, @RequestParam(name = "maxDate") String max_date, @RequestParam(USERID) String user_id, @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorizationHeader) {
```

where dataType can be one of either String, Map, Object or Calendar.  I created another GetMapping as follows

```or-tag-here
@GetMapping(value = "/dawson/v1/signInReq")
public ResponseEntity<String> mySignInRequest(@RequestBody Map<String, String> paramMap, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

However, when I try to access the /dawson/v1/signInReq, it still hits the first mapping and not the signInReq one.  Is there a way to exclude signInReq as a match for {dataType}?

I do have the workaround of listing all possible dataTypes in the first mapping above but was wondering if there was a better way to handle it(Regex maybe?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used a REGEX pattern to resolve the filtering of path as follows:

```or-tag-here
@GetMapping(value = "/dawson/v1/{dataType:^.*(?!signInReq)}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
```

The Regex will only match requests that are not signInReq.